# parameters value are zero in HoltWinters() when fitting seasonal model

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using `HoltWinters()` in R, to fit the model. I am not able to understand why the model is giving zero value for alpha, beta and gamma.What to do in this case? Below is the data and code. Thanks in advance.

```
x<-c(2835,  2970,   2565,   2970,   2700,   4995,   3375,   
2430,   2295,   3375,   3780,   1755,   2970,   2835,   
1890,   1485,   3780,   2430,   3780,   1215,   3915,   
1485,   3375,   3510,   2970,   2700,   2025,   3105,
3645,   2721,   1215,   4995,   2430,   2700,   1620,   
2025,   2430,   3780,   2295,   4860,   1350,   3645,   
6885,   2295,   1350,   2565,   2835,   2970,   2970,   
2970,   4185,   3105,   1080,   2565,   2295,   3105,
1890,   3386,   3375,   3105,   2565,   2970,   5265,   
5400,   2565,   1890,   3240,   4050,   2160,   4725,   
5805,   6615,   2565,   4455,   1620,   2025,   1620,   
2835,   1485,   4455,   3510,   1215,   2025,   3510,
3510,   2160,   1755,   1620,   4050,   2295,   2970,   
2108,   3510,   4725,   2565,   5535,   2025,   1080,   
675,    135,    2700,   3904,   2835,   3105,   1755,   
2565,   1755,   2970,   1080,   1755)

x_ts<-ts(x,frequency=52)
hw<-hw<-HoltWinters(x_ts,seasonal="multiplicative")

Output:
hw

Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and multiplicative seasonal component.

Call:
HoltWinters(x = x_ts, seasonal = "multiplicative")

Smoothing parameters:
alpha: 0
beta : 0
gamma: 0

Coefficients:
        [,1]
a   3108.2165107
b      3.6027043
s1     1.0734921
s2     0.9859404
s3     0.8155082
s4     0.9450738
...
```

Comment: Your time series appears to be a bit over two years of weekly data.  You've asked HoltWinters to find seasonal factors as well as alpha and beta so it returns 52 seasonal coefficients (s1 ... s52) plus starting values.  It finds the seasonal coefficients first and then, apparently, treats the rest as residuals due to the seasonal factors and so returns alpha and beta as zero. Basically you need more years of data to find alpha and beta.   Just for demonstration, you could set frequency = 12 in x_ts.  HoltWinters would then return 12 seasonal factors plus alpha and beta.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not enough to fit large frequency so you can  reduce the frequency means you will get the non zero alpha value.
For Example:

```
x_ts<-ts(x,frequency=5)
```